# Flutter dependencies not working

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am trying to get the tutorial project `startup_namer` running. I am getting following error after I added `english_words` dependency on `pubspec.yaml`

```
Resolving dependencies...
The Flutter SDK is not available.
Flutter users should run `flutter packages get` instead of `pub get`.
```

Any idea on how to resolve this? I followed Google getting started documentation but didn't work out for me :(

Comment: ... you (or your IDE) is running `pub get` instead of `flutter packages get`.  Run `flutter packages get` to get your dependencies.

Comment: Do you get this from Android Studio or from command line?

Answer (score 5):

Run this command in terminal/Command Prompt

```
flutter doctor
```

It automatically installs the missing dependencies or download the flutter sdk if necessary

if already install still problem exists run

```
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install) to get the Flutter SDK installed on your machine. If you already have the SDK and want to install the dependencies in `pubspec.yaml`, run this command in the project's root folder:

`flutter packages get`

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error message in Android Studio then you probably don't have the Flutter plugin installed.

I just could reproduce that and for example opening the `pubspec.yaml` asked me to install the plugin and then the error was fixed.
You can also install it manually using the preferences.